# How to parse java command line

Tags: java, command-line

I get a command string like this `java -jar -Dsome.port=1112 server.jar`. 
I would like to produce another command string like `java -jar -Dsome.port=1113 server.jar`. Without direct string manipulation.

I tried `Apache Commons CLI` 1.2 but cannot figure out how to do what I want.

I tried `OptionBuilder.withArgName("Dsome.port").hasArg(true).create("Dsome.port")`
But it says

> opt contains illegal character value '.'

Comment: `-D` command line options are read by `System.getProperty("some.port")`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca What I get is  just the raw String, which is not passed to my running jvm.

Comment: Why don’t you want to do string manipulation when its a string you have? Why complicate things?